# Forcing Template to save as an xlsm but afterwards allowing saving as a pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I've created a xltm document for use in my workplace. The majority of users have xls set as their default save option thus when people save this document after configuring they need to be forced to save as an xlsm instead or they will lose functionality. In order to override this I have used the below code (borrowed and adapted from someone else's question elsewhere):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim vFilename As Variant

'Disable events so "new save" doesn't re-trigger this event
Application.EnableEvents = False

If SaveAsUI = True Then ' User selected SaveAs instead of Save

Cancel = True ' Cancel the user's original save action

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Simulate built in "SaveAs", Use desired "IntialFilename" & filter
vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\Temp\Development.xlsm", fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), (*.xlsm")

If vFilename <> False Then

    'Save file with desired parameters
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End If

Debug.Print vFilename

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Re-enable events
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This works as intended, forcing users to save as xlsm after first use of the template. However, as the code stays with the sheet it means that the newly configured sheet can now never be saved as anything other than an xlsm during the whole of it's lifetime and usage.

This is problematic as at some point down the line it's highly probable that users will want to save individual sheets within the workbook as pdf's to present to people they'd rather did not have access to the actual workbook and it's underlying formulae.

Is there any way I can cause the code above to be removed from the file after the initial save to xlsm by the user? Or add to the above code to also allow saving to a PDF file format?

I realise a workaround would be for people to use a "PDF Printer" such as CutePDF to save the file instead of the in built save function but this would not be appropriate for the level of IT competency in my workplace.

Any attempts towards an answer much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you save the file as `.xlsx` (which eliminates automatically any VBA code attached to the file)? If you prefer to save it as `.xlsm` you can still (initially) save it as `.xlsx` (to remove the code) and then save it again as `.xlsm`. Alternatively you should look at this solution to alter VBA code in other files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523172/excel-2010-vba-macro-to-change-the-content-of-a-module-in-another-file or http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Is this the only procedure in the XLTM file? Or are there other macros/procedures that also need to be preserved? In other words, do you strictly require that the file's lifetime needs to remain in XLSM format (except for external distribution)? If not, then @Ralph suggestion above is a good one to just save as XLSX instead of XLSM.

Comment: I do require that it stays a xlsm. The wookbook contains at least eight other procedures, five of which are only useful later on in the lifecycle of the sheet (perhaps years down the line). Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**: Embed a new macro/button that will export to PDF with code. This will still force all manual saves to adhere to the .xlsm restrictions.

```
Sub ExportToPDF()

    Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevent the saveas restriction from running

    'Get filename for saving PDF
    Dim vFilename As Variant
    vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\Temp\Development.pdf", fileFilter:="PDF (*.pdf), *.pdf")

    If vFilename <> False Then

        'Export PDF with selected filename
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=vFilename, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True 'Reset event handler

End Sub
```

**Option 2**: Modify your BeforeSave subroutine to allow .xlsm or .pdf saves.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim vFilename As Variant

'Disable events so "new save" doesn't re-trigger this event
Application.EnableEvents = False

If SaveAsUI = True Then ' User selected SaveAs instead of Save

Cancel = True ' Cancel the user's original save action

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Simulate built in "SaveAs", Use desired "IntialFilename" & filter
vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\Temp\Development.xlsm", fileFilter:="All Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Save As: XLSM or PDF Only!") '

If vFilename <> False Then

    'Check to see if user is trying to save as .xlsm, .pdf, or other
    If Right(vFilename, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
        'Save file with desired parameters
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vFilename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ElseIf Right(vFilename, 4) = ".pdf" Then
        'Export PDF with selected filename
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=vFilename, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Else
        'Alert user and do not save
        MsgBox "This workbook can only be saved in .xlsm or .pdf formats. Please try again."
    End If
End If

Debug.Print vFilename

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Re-enable events
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, both of the above are workable solutions. Option 2 was closest to the solution I was looking for and would be my clear preference, were it not for the fact that it forces the user to type the file extension manually rather than be able to select it from the usual drop down menu. For this reason I may go with Option 1 instead.