# VBA macro which writes a new macro from string on the fly

Tags: string, vba, excel, module

Is it possible to create Excel VBA macro from a string variable?

Suppose we have FirstMacro:

```
Sub FirstMacro()
    Dim MyString
    MyString = "Sub SecondMacro()" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "MsgBox " & Chr(34) & "Hello" & Chr(34) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "End Sub"
    Debug.Print MyString
    'Here be code that magicly creates SecondMacro
End Sub
```

Running the macro, I want to create SecondMacro which is stored in VBA string variable. The second macro can be created either below in the same module or in a new module.

So the second macro from string looks like this:

```
Sub SecondMacro()
MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel 2010 VBA macro to change the content of a module in another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523172/excel-2010-vba-macro-to-change-the-content-of-a-module-in-another-file)

Comment: In order to write code to your VBA project you must allow access to the VBA project which Microsoft discourages so strongly that they haven't created a backdoor by which code might create such access - anybody could come and do what he wants with your machine. VBA access should be granted strictly temporarily, meaning for all practical purposes that you can't do what you want without sharing your PC with hackers. However, you can write code to select existing macros depending upon what is stored in a variable or read from a worksheet, if that will serve your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is possible.  It should be noted that you can't add/delete from the module you're running code in.

This will append the code at the end of the module.  If you can avoid this though you should, I only use it for adding code to buttons that I've added programatically.

```
With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).VBProject.VBComponents("MyModuleHere").CodeModule
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, "Sub... End Sub"
End With
```

So to add to the "MyModuleHere" code module (assuming you have a module named that), drop this in:

```
Sub addcode()
    Dim subtext As String
    subtext = "Sub PrintStuff" & vbCrLf & "msgbox ""Hello World""" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).VBProject.VBComponents("MyModuleHere").CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, subtext
    End With
End Sub
```

As usual, CPearson adds some really useful insight:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

With regard to removing code, which I think you're hinting at in your comment, I use the below function to find a sub name, and remove it (this assumes that I will know the length of the sub):

```
Function ClearModule(strShapeName As String)
Dim start As Long
Dim Lines As Long
Dim i As Variant, a As Variant

    With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).VBProject.VBComponents("MyModuleHere").CodeModule
        For i = .CountOfLines To 1 Step -1
            If Left(.Lines(i, 1), 8 + Len(strShapeName)) = "Sub " & strShapeName & "_Cli" Then
                .DeleteLines i, 6
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This is almost good. Would be better if it added code to module (not sheet code), and even better if it added code to new module of specified name, dropping it earlier if it exists:-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin try the section titled "Adding A Procedure To A Module" in the link at the bottom of my answer :)  Will update the answer later if i get time

Answer (score 1):

Here you have more or less all variations which, hopefully, will solve your problem. To test this code copy all of it in a normal code module (by default "Module1") Rename it as "Remin" and write "FirstMacro" in cell A1 of the worksheet you activate, a number in cell A2. Then run the first of the following procedures directly from the VBE window.

```
Sub SelectMacroToRun()
    ' 04 Apr 2017

    Dim MacroName As String
    Dim Arg1 As String
    Dim Outcome As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        MacroName = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        Arg1 = .Cells(2, 1).Value
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Outcome = Application.Run(ActiveSheet.name & "." & MacroName, Arg1)
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "The macro """ & MacroName & """ wasn't found", _
               vbInformation, "Error message"
    Else
        If Outcome <> xlNone Then MsgBox "Outcome = " & Outcome
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FirstMacro(Optional ByVal Dummy As String) As Long

    MsgBox "First Macro"
    FirstMacro = xlNone
End Function

Private Function SecondMacro(Arg1 As Long) As Long

    MsgBox "Second Macro" & vbCr & _
           "Argument is " & Arg1

    SecondMacro = Arg1 * 111
End Function
```

The code will run the FirstMacro, reading the name from the worksheet. Change that name to "SecondMacro" to call the second macro instead. The second macro requires an argument, the first only accepts it and does nothing with it. You don't need to pass any argument, but this code shows how to pass (as many as you want, comma separated) and it also shows how to ignore it - the argument is passed to a dummy variable in the FirstMacro, and the function also returns nothing.

```
Application.Run "Remin" & MacroName, Arg1
```

Would just run the macro (it could be a sub). Omit the argument if you don't want to pass an argument. "Remin" is the name of the code sheet where the called macro resides. This name could be extended to include the name of another workbook. However, if the called macro isn't in the same module as the caller it can't be Private.